# "I had to go see about a girl"

Tags: grammaticality

In one of my favourite movies *Good Will Hunting*, the main character played by Matt Damon says

> I had to go **see about** a girl.

Is this sentence correct, and if so does it mean the same as the following?

> I had to go **see** a girl.

Comment: +1 Simply because it's a quote from Good Will Hunting, hah. :)

Comment: I guess the phrase is also meant to invoke the phrase [“I have to go see a man about a dog”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/origin-exact-meaning-of-the-phrase-i-have-to-go-see-a-man-about-a-dog).

Comment: +1 Simply because you bumped it, and I know how it feels. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since "see about" can be used as a verb phrase, the grammar is in fact correct. I can however see why you feel this phrase is unnatural - it's certainly not commonly used.

The [following definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/see%20about) (in particular part *b*) should give you the right understanding.

> **see about,**
>   a. to investigate; inquire about.
>   b. to turn one's attention to; take care of: He said he would see about getting the license plates.

In other words, quote could be rewritten more formally as:

> I must turn my attention to a [certain] girl.

Comment: +1 good explanation. Note that (out of context) it doesn't necessarily imply that he would be seeing the girl herself (though he may be) - but could mean, for example, that he is making some preparations or doing a favour for her.

Comment: @psmears: That's very true. With the context of the film added, it becomes quite obvious however.